# How to avoid the ASCII 0D 0A in text message

Tags: powershell, ascii, sms-gateway

I have powershell script which sends text message through a sms-gateway. I get the message content from a txt file without any returns but I always receive text messages with the content and the last characters 0D 0A. How can I avoid this characters? 
This is my powershell code:

```
    $path = "C:\test.txt"
$EmailAddress = "test@test.com"
$smtpServer = "123.456.789.10"
$smsGateway = "0123456789@smsgateway.com"
$subject = "asdawadWA5556WAAA"

$body = get-content $path
[string]$stringBody = $body |out-string
send-mailmessage -From $EmailAddress -To $smsGateway -Subject $subject -Body $stringBody -Smtpserver $smtpServer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PowerShell strings are really .NET strings, you can use the handy [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters; theses include `0x0D` and `0x0A`, the ASCII carriage return and line feed characters that make up a standard Windows newline phrase.

All you have to do is add the `.Trim()` call to the argument to the `Body` parameter:

```
-Body $stringBody.Trim()
```